# ssh into VM instance with different username from local

Tags: gcloud

I wanted to be able to ssh into my VM instance. I was able to change my ssh config by,
`gcloud compute config-ssh`. This changed my ssh config and said that I could ssh by,

```bash
ssh server-name-some-stuff
```

For some reason, I do the above I get public key denied error as it tries to use `username1` (the one on my local machine). But if I do,

```bash
ssh username2@server-name-some-stuff
```

I am able to ssh into it. How could I call `gcloud compute config-ssh` such that it uses `username2`.

Answer (score 0):

The [`gcloud compute config-ssh`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/config-ssh) does not have such option:

> SYNOPSIS
>
> `gcloud compute config-ssh [--dry-run] [--force-key-file-overwrite] [--remove] [--ssh-config-file=SSH_CONFIG_FILE] [--ssh-key-file=SSH_KEY_FILE] [GCLOUD_WIDE_FLAG …]`
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> `gcloud compute config-ssh` makes
> SSHing to virtual machine instances easier by adding an alias for each
> instance to the user SSH configuration (`~/.ssh/config`) file.

You would have to edit the `~/.ssh/config` manually. You could either add `User username2` to each of the `Host` sections or, if the username is same for all the hosts, use wildcard hosts like:

```
Host *
  User username2

Host *.example.com
  User username2
```